# Cycle background with text overlay effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I found [a really cool example](https://jsfiddle.net/8adg75ba/18/) for cycling background images using JavaScript and jQuery.

What would be the best approach to adding an overlay text description effect for each slide?

So for instance, each slide will also have a text description overlayed somewhere on each image with it's own style . Would it be possible to have this text also come in with it's own effects. So the image fades in, and then the text description slides in from the left, and so on

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <div id="background_cycler">

        <img class="active" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/View_from_a_ridge_between_Segla_and_Hesten%2C_Senja%2C_Norway%2C_2014_August.jpg/1920px-View_from_a_ridge_between_Segla_and_Hesten%2C_Senja%2C_Norway%2C_2014_August.jpg" width="1000px" height="1000px" alt="" />

        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Amanhecer_no_Hercules_--.jpg/1920px-Amanhecer_no_Hercules_--.jpg" alt="" width="1000px" height="1000px" />

        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Giant_Manta_AdF.jpg/1920px-Giant_Manta_AdF.jpg" alt="" width="1000px" height="1000px" />
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#background_cycler').hide();

window.cycleImages = function() {
    var $active = $('#background_cycler .active');
    var $next = ($('#background_cycler .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#background_cycler .active').next() : $('#background_cycler img:first');
    $next.css('z-index', 2); //move the next image up the pile
    $active.fadeOut(1500, function() { //fade out the top image
        $active.css('z-index', 1).show().removeClass('active'); //reset the z-index and unhide the image
        $next.css('z-index', 3).addClass('active'); //make the next image the top one
    });
}

$(window).load(function() {


    $('#background_cycler').fadeIn(1500); //fade the background back in once all the images are loaded
    // run every 7s
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
})
```

**CSS**

```
#background_cycler {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

#background_cycler img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#background_cycler img.active {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: Just have it operate on divs instead of imgs. Put your img inside the div with your text tag right before it and position the text absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution like Andy's, but keeping the `img` tags:

https://jsfiddle.net/2y8fo13d/

Comment: Say I wanted to have the spin ease in some how with a little effect from the left or right. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Check out the 'transition' css property. Here's something to get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/x65qbv88/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `img` tags, you can use more generic `div` tags to act as the slides. Then you can fill them with whatever content you wish, check out this as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/00gow9Lt/1/

Here I have used `div` tags with some simple text and the original images as backgrounds.

You can style each one's content separately with css for a different look, but to have sliding effects on the text itself would require significantly more code. For that I would suggest reading up on jQuery animations in more detail.